# Java: String.equalsIgnoreCase(. . .) not working

Tags: java

I am developing a small application in Java. The following if condition never becomes true, does any body be knows the actual reason?

```
public int foo()
{

String sTitle = "title";
if (sTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(MyCustomObject.sTitle))
    return 5;
else
    return 6;
}
```

It always returns 6. I ran it in debug mode and saw that both strings contains same value.
I also tried swapping the positions of both strings like:

```
MyCustomObject.sTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(sTitle)
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: Post the code that assigns values to `MyCustomObject.sTitle`.

Comment: You should post code here that you've actually tried and isn't working.  This won't even compile.  Add the assignment for `MyCustomObject.sTitle` in the same spot as `sTitle` and see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to insert this before your if and tell us the output:

system.out.println(sTitle+"~"+MyCustomObject.sTitle+"="+sTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(MyCustomObject.sTitle));

Comment: Try trimming each String, maybe you have some extra whitespace at the beginning or end.

Comment: While it is a nice dream that both strings have the same value, it appears that Java disagrees with you.  consider the details.  If the MyCustomObject.sTitle has a null at the end then it is in no way the same as "title" because "title" != "title\0"

Comment: +1 for making sure the string you're comparing to is trimmed.

Comment: Its almost impossible to comment where you went wrong without looking at MyCustomObject.sTitle

Answer (score 4):

The actual reason is that `MyCustomObject.sTitle` does not have the value "title" or any case variants.

Check where and when that variable is assigned.

Comment: I clearly wrote that both strings have same value.
No need to check where that value is comming from, i simply place a break point over the if condition and hover my mouse pointer over both strings and found that both have same values even with the same case

Comment: @Jame either the values differ or you're not posting exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Jame can you copy/paste the value that you see in debugger? It may look like 'title', but it's actually not.

Comment: @srkavin: I already chk that thing as well, there is nothing such thing

Comment: @Jonathon: I am not able to paste the actual code due to security issues, sorry for that. But i mange to figure the problem there is a white space in begining of string. Sorry for downvote, I will up-vote it now thx

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `MyCustomObject.sTitle` is a string as well.

My first attempt at debugging would be to add the following line before you test the equality:
`System.out.println("*"+MyCustomObject.sTitle+"*");` 
and check for whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this code to the foo method:

```
if (sTitle.length() != MyCustomObject.sTitle.length())
{
  System.out.println("I hate the truth");
}
else
{
  System.out.println("The mystery remains!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EqualsIgnoreCase method

Compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations. Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length, and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case.
Two characters c1 and c2 are considered the same, ignoring case if at least one of the following is true:

The two characters are the same (as compared by the == operator).
Applying the method Character.toUpperCase(char) to each character produces the same result.
Applying the method Character.toLowerCase(char) to each character produces the same result.

Based on the above the value of MyCustomObject.sTitle is not matching any of the above criteria.

Answer (score 1):

as previous authors have written MyCustomObject.sTitle does not return any variant of "title". You could try running this piece of code and you can prove for yourself that it's not the equalsIgnoreCase method that doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(foo());
}

public static int foo()
{

String sTitle = "title";
if (sTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(MyCustomObject.sTitle))
    return 5;
else
    return 6;
}

public static class MyCustomObject {
    public static String sTitle = "TITLE";
}
```